# Removing old kernels seemingly removed graphics driver, is it safe to reboot?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, boot, drivers

Removing old kernels seemingly removed graphics driver, is it safe to reboot?

While doing a routine `sudo apt upgrade`, I received a `No space left on device` error. It turned out that kernels kept accumulating on `/boot/` and the partition was running low on space.

Automatically purging old kernels did not work.

```
$  sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

So I filtered the list of headers and images.

```
$ dpkg --list | grep -E 'linux-image|linux-headers|linux-modules' | awk '{ print $2 }'
linux-headers-5.10.0-20-amd64
linux-headers-5.10.0-20-common
linux-headers-5.10.0-21-amd64
linux-headers-5.10.0-21-common
linux-headers-5.10.0-22-amd64
linux-headers-5.10.0-22-common
linux-headers-5.10.0-23-amd64
linux-headers-5.10.0-23-common
linux-headers-5.10.0-24-amd64
linux-headers-5.10.0-24-common
linux-headers-5.10.0-25-amd64
linux-headers-5.10.0-25-common
linux-headers-amd64
linux-image-5.10.0-18-amd64
linux-image-5.10.0-19-amd64
linux-image-5.10.0-20-amd64
linux-image-5.10.0-21-amd64
linux-image-5.10.0-22-amd64
linux-image-5.10.0-23-amd64
linux-image-5.10.0-24-amd64
linux-image-5.10.0-25-amd64
linux-image-amd64
```

I purged all headers and images from `5.10.0-18` to `5.10.0-23`. However while purging images I saw unexpected messages:

```
Removing linux-image-5.10.0-23-amd64 (5.10.179-3) ...
/etc/kernel/prerm.d/dkms:
dkms: removing: nvidia 535.98 (5.10.0-23-amd64) (x86_64)

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  nvidia
Version: 535.98
Kernel:  5.10.0-23-amd64 (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

nvidia.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.10.0-23-amd64/kernel/drivers/video/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-uvm.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.10.0-23-amd64/kernel/drivers/video/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-modeset.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.10.0-23-amd64/kernel/drivers/video/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-drm.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.10.0-23-amd64/kernel/drivers/video/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


nvidia-peermem.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.10.0-23-amd64/kernel/drivers/video/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.
dkms: removing: v4l2loopback 0.12.5 (5.10.0-23-amd64) (x86_64)

-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  v4l2loopback
Version: 0.12.5
Kernel:  5.10.0-23-amd64 (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

v4l2loopback.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/5.10.0-23-amd64/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod...

DKMS: uninstall completed.
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-23-amd64
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found background image: /usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-25-amd64
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-25-amd64
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.10.0-24-amd64
Warning: os-prober will be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Its output will be used to detect bootable binaries on them and create new boot entries.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

```
$ dpkg --list | grep -E 'linux-image|linux-headers|linux-modules' | awk '{ print $2 }'
linux-headers-5.10.0-24-amd64
linux-headers-5.10.0-24-common
linux-headers-5.10.0-25-amd64
linux-headers-5.10.0-25-common
linux-headers-amd64
linux-image-5.10.0-24-amd64
linux-image-5.10.0-25-amd64
linux-image-amd64
```

Did I accidentally remove my graphics drivers? Or is it just fine since the drivers are also present in the more recent kernels anyway?

Just in case I manually regenerated `initrd` images for the two remaining kernels.

```
$ sudo rm /boot/initrd.img*
$ sudo update-initramfs -c -k all
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-24-amd64
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-25-amd64
$ ls /boot/
config-5.10.0-24-amd64  grub                lost+found          vmlinuz-5.10.0-24-amd64
config-5.10.0-25-amd64  initrd.img-5.10.0-24-amd64  System.map-5.10.0-24-amd64  vmlinuz-5.10.0-25-amd64
efi         initrd.img-5.10.0-25-amd64  System.map-5.10.0-25-amd64
```

```
$ uname -r
5.10.0-24-amd64
```

After a reboot my PC should boot into `5.10.0-25`. Is it safe to reboot the system, or is there more configuration to do such as notifying GRUB about the purged kernels to ensure I don't fry my system?

Comment: You should run `sudo dkms status` and check if you have a nvidia module for the target kernel. Because you're showing things that were deleted but didn't show things that were added.

Comment: Just in case, I'd have a live USB handy so that if someone went wrong, I could repair the system from there.

Comment: You don't need to manually update your grub config here - `update-grub` is automatically run after installing or removing `kernel-image` packages.  You can see that in your output above, immediately after `/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:`

Answer (score 1):

It's completely normal and expected for compiled dkms modules to be removed when the kernel image they were compiled for is removed.

If you run `dkms status` you'll probably see that the modules are still  installed for the kernel image packages that you didn't purge (i.e. `linux-image-5.10.0-24-amd64` and `linux-image-5.10.0-25-amd64`).

If you don't see that, then you may have accidentally uninstalled the `nvidia-kernel-dkms` package too - the solution to that is to re-install it.

---

On a related note, I strongly recommend using `apt-mark hold` to hold both the  `linux-image-amd64` and `linux-headers-amd64` packages, and only installing upgraded kernel packages manually, e.g. with something like (as root, from a root shell or with `sudo`):

```
apt-get -u install linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64 ; \
apt-mark hold linux-image-amd64 linux-headers-amd64
```

Why? because dkms packages are occasionally incompatible with newer kernels, so you need to wait for an updated version of the dkms package before you upgrade the kernel.  (BTW, sometimes the updated package arrives quickly, sometimes you have to wait for days or weeks or even longer. Just have patience, it's [not worth breaking your system](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian) just to get the shiniest newest thing, especially when shiny & new doesn't automatically mean better or "adds something useful that you actually **need**").

You should hold your nvidia-related packages for the same reason.  I use the following script (called `list-nvidia.sh`) on my systems (at least, those which still have nvidia GPUs, I'm gradually moving them over to radeon cards):

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# script: list-nvidia.sh
# author: Craig Sanders <cas@taz.net.au>
# license: Public Domain (this script is too trivial to be anything else)

# options:
# default/none    list the packages, one per line
# -v              verbose (dpkg -l) list the packages
# -h              hold the packages with apt-mark
# -u              unhold the packages with apt-mark

# build an array of currently-installed nvidia packages.
PKGS=( $(dpkg -l '*nvidia*' '*cuda*' '*vdpau*' 2>/dev/null| awk '/^[hi][^n]/ && ! /mesa/ {print $2}') )

if [ "$1" == "-v" ] ; then
  dpkg -l "${PKGS[@]}" | cat
elif [ "$1" == "-h" ] ; then
  apt-mark hold "${PKGS[@]}"
elif [ "$1" == "-u" ] ; then
  apt-mark unhold "${PKGS[@]}"
else
  printf "%s\n" "${PKGS[@]}"
fi
```

I run `list-nvidia.sh -h` to hold all the nvidia-related packages then, when I want to upgrade the nvidia driver, I run:

```
apt-get install $(list-nvidia.sh) ; \
  list-nvidia.sh -h
```

I have a similar `list-zfs.sh` script for ZFS dkms modules:

```
#! /bin/bash
#
# script: list-zfs.sh
# author: Craig Sanders <cas@taz.net.au>
# license: Public Domain (this script is too trivial to be anything else)

# options:
# default/none    list the packages, one per line
# -v              verbose (dpkg -l) list the packages
# -h              hold the packages with apt-mark
# -u              unhold the packages with apt-mark


# build an array of currently-installed zfs packages.
PKGS=( $(dpkg -l '*libnvpair*linux' '*libuutil*linux*' '*zfs*' '*zpool*' 'spl' 'spl-dkms' 'spl-kernel-modules' 'zfs-kernel-modules' 2>/dev/null | awk '/^[hi][^n]/ && ! /zfsnap|libvirt/ {print $2}') )

if [ "$1" == "-v" ] ; then
  dpkg -l "${PKGS[@]}" | cat
elif [ "$1" == "-h" ] ; then
  apt-mark hold "${PKGS[@]}"
elif [ "$1" == "-u" ] ; then
  apt-mark unhold "${PKGS[@]}"
else
  printf "%s\n" "${PKGS[@]}"
fi
```

I'd probably have a `list-kernels.sh` script too (and it wouldn't be hard at all to modify one of the above to do that), but I already have most of that with `dlocate -k` and `dlocate -K`.  One of my uses for this is to mark all kernel images and dkms modules as manually installed with `apt-mark manual $(dlocate -k)`, so that they will only be removed/purged when I want them to be.

---

Finally, you almost never need to use `grep` if you're also using `awk` as awk can do everything grep can do and more.   e.g. your command:

```
dpkg --list | grep -E 'linux-image|linux-headers|linux-modules' |
  awk '{ print $2 }'
```

can be shortened to:

```
dpkg -l | awk '/linux-image|linux-headers|linux-modules/ { print $2 }'
```

or, better yet, match on only the second field of `dpkg -l`'s output:

```
dpkg -l | awk '$2 ~ /^linux-(image|headers|modules)/ { print $2 }'
```

you can also take advantage of awk's ability to combine regex pattern matches on specific fields with boolean expressions.  e.g.:

```
dpkg -l | awk '$2 ~ /^linux-(image|headers|modules)/ &&
               $3 ~ /^5\.10\.(1[89]|2[0-3])-/ { print $2 }'
```

That would give you a list of packages you could append to an `apt-get purge` command (possibly with command substitution, as with the `apt-get install` examples above).  I use something like this routinely, whenever I need to purge old installed kernels.

Comment: You never know when a `kernel-image-*` or `nvidia-kernel-dkms` package will be incompatible with each other, so I recommend creating a minimal VM for testing upgrades of either **before** you apply the upgrade to your real system. When there's a new kernel-image and/or a new nvidia-kernel-dkms, start the VM and try upgrading those packages. If the dkms package compiles OK in the VM, it should be safe to perform the same upgrade on your real system.  The VM doesn't need to have access to an nvidia card - all that matters is if it compiles or not. I do this for both nvidia and zfs dkms packages.

Comment: one last thing: be careful to never purge the currently running kernel (this is another benefit of holding kernel packages - they'll never be auto-removed).  Always test that a newer kernel will boot (and, preferably, doesn't introduce new problems...but that can be tricky because new problems aren't always immediately obvious) before removing the old one...you may need to revert to it.